# Number of fields returned by awk

Tags: shell, awk, field

Is there a way to get `awk` to return the number of fields that meet a field-separator criteria? Say, for instance, the file contains:

```
a b c d
```

So, `awk -F=' ' | <something>` should return 4.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `NF` variable is set to the total number of fields in the input record. So:

```
echo "a b c d" | awk --field-separator=" " "{ print NF }"
```

will display

```
4
```

Note, however, that:

```
echo -e "a b c d\na b" | awk --field-separator=" " "{ print NF }"
```

will display:

```
4
2
```

Hope this helps, and happy awking

Comment: The default field separator is space, so `echo "a b c d" | awk {'print NF'}` suffices..

Answer (score 6):

`NF` gives the number of fields for a given record:

```
[]$ echo "a b c d" | gawk '{print NF}'
4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to know the set of all the numbers of fields in a multiline content you can run:

```
X | awk '{print NF}' | sort -n | uniq
```

being `X` a command that outputs content in the standard output: `cat`, `echo`, etc. Example:

With **file.txt:**

```
a b
b c
c d
e t a
e u
```

The command `cat file.txt | awk '{print NF}' | sort -n | uniq` will print:

```
2
3
```

And with **file2.txt:**

```
a b
b c
c d
e u
```

The command `cat file2.txt | awk '{print NF}' | sort -n | uniq` will print:

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

[awk(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?awk) on FreeBSD does not recognize `--field-separator`. Use `-v` instead:

```
echo "a b c d" | awk -v FS=" " "{ print NF }"
```

It is [a portable, POSIX way](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) to define the field separator.