# Use awk/bash to add 1 to all columns but first

Tags: awk

I have a table in which the header is the sample list and the first column is the gene list, and the rest is expression values for each gene in each sample. I want to add a pseudocount of 1 to all values, and I currently do it as such:

```
cat <(head -n 1 TPM/QuickTest_Dataset.table) \
<(tail -n +2 TPM/QuickTest_Dataset.table | awk '{print $1, $2+1, $3+1, $4+1, $5+1, $6+1, $7+1, $8+1, $9+1, $10+1, $11+1, $12+1, $13+1, $14+1, $15+1, $16+1, $17+1, $18+1, $19+1, $20+1, $21+1}' | sed 's, ,\t,g') > StringTie-TPM_Homo_sapiens_GRCh38.Exp9-PMacrophageM1.protein_coding.table
```

However, the amount of samples isn't always 20 (amount of columns isn't always 21), sometimes more sometimes less and I have to manually adjust it each time.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one `awk` call:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} FNR==1{print; next} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i=$i+1}1' infile > outfile
```

Comment: could be done in single block too: `FNR>1{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i++} 1'`

Comment: `$i=$i+1` = `$i+=1` or just `$i++`.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is great language. Just iterate over fields and increment them.

```
awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NR; ++i) $i += 1; } 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google-search "awk Number of fields" let me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582405/number-of-fields-returned-by-awk), mentioning the variable `NF` you might use.

The search for "awk for-loop" redirects to [this URL](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-awk-do-while-for-loops/), where the following simple `awk` for-loop is demonstrated (this also uses the `NF` variable):

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) total = total+$i }; END { print total }'
```

This might give you a good start to solve this issue.